# Qlikview - append data to Excel

Tags: excel, qlikview

I have qvw file with sql query

```
 Data:
 LOAD  source, color, date;

 select source, color, date
 as Mytable;

 STORE Data into  [..\QV_Data\Data.qvd] (qvd);
```

Then I export data to excel and save.

I need something to do that automatically instead of me

I need to run query every day and automatically send data to excel but keep old data in excel and append new value.

Can qlikview to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to create some crazy macro that runs after a reload task in on open-trigger. If you schedule a windows task that execute a bat file with path to qlikview.exe with the filepath as parameters and -r flag for reload(?) you can probably accomplish this... there are a lot of code of similar projects to be found on google.

I suggest adding this to the loadscript instead.

```
STORE Table into  [..\QV_Data\Data.csv] (txt);
```

and then open that file in excel.

If you need to append data you could concatenate new data onto the previous data.. something like:

```
Data:
load * from Data.csv;

//add latest data
concatenate(Data)
LOAD  source, color, date from ...

STORE Data into  [..\QV_Data\Data.csv] (txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the desktop version so you don't have access to the Qlikview Management Console (if you do, this is obviously the best way).

So, without the Console, you should create a txt file with this command: `"C:\Program Files\QlikView\Qv.exe" /r "\\thePathToYourFile\test.qvw"`. Save this file with `.cmd` file extension. After that you can schedule this command file with the windows task scheduler.